# html5 card matching game - can't separate images from a sprite

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a big sprite image  which has around 16 images in it. I am want to cut images from the sprite and paste on the background image dynamically.
 
**Edit:** here is the Html code: 
   [image]

here is the css code :

```
 body{
text-align:center;
background: BROWN url(../images/bg.jpg);
}
#game{
border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px solid GRAY;
background: DARKGREEN url(../images/table.jpg);
width: 500px;
height: 460px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: flex;
justify-content: center; 
align-items: center;
}
.card{
perspective: 600px;
width: 80px;
height: 120px;
position: absolute;
transition: all .3s;
}

.face{
border-radius: 10px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
transition-property: opacity, transition, box-shadow;
transition-duration: .3s;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.front{
background: GRAY url(../images/deck.png) 0 -480px;
}
.back{
background: LIGHTGREY url(../images/deck.png);
transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-180deg); 
}

.card:havor .face, .card-flipped .face {
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aaa;
}
.card-flipped .front{
transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}
.card-flipped .back{
transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
}
.card-removed{
opacity: 0;
}

.cardAJ {background-position: -800px 0;} 
.cardAQ {background-position: -880px 0;} 
.cardAK {background-position: -960px 0;} 
.cardBJ {background-position: -800px -120px;} 
.cardBQ {background-position: -880px -120px;} 
.cardBK {background-position: -960px -120px;} 
.cardCJ {background-position: -800px -240px;} 
.cardCQ {background-position: -880px -240px;} 
.cardCK {background-position: -960px -240px;} 
.cardDJ {background-position: -800px -360px;} 
.cardDQ {background-position: -880px -360px;} 
.cardDK {background-position: -960px -360px;}
```

images

## **bg**

[image: bg]

### **deck**

*
[image: deck]

### **table**

[image: table]

I am trying to split the image deck into pieces dynamically i.e. using jQuery code which is as follows:

```
$(function(){
//clone 12 copies of the card
for(var i=0; i<11;i++)
{
    $(".card:first-child").clone().appendTo("#cards");
}
// initialise each card's position 
$("#cards").children().each(function(index){
 //align the cards to be 4*3 ourselves.
 var x = ($(this).width()+20)*(index%4);
 var y = ($(this).hegith+20)*Math.floor(index/4);
 $(this).css("transform"," tranlateX( "+x+" px) tranlateY( "+y+" px)");

});
```

});

Please   tell me what changes shall I make to get the desired result.

Comment: can you create a codepen or jsfiddle please? that way i can better help you

Comment: @SandrinaPereira I am not getting what you are asking for! shall I create  google drive link?

Comment: No need for that, use codepen.com or https://jsfiddle.net/. Is quicker

Comment: @SandrinaPereira  here is the link  for codepen - http://codepen.io/amirhasan/pen/LRJBON

Comment: i think you CSS is wrong. You stack your cards with `position: absolute`. See example here `https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/huj3whop/`

Comment: and your `<div class="face back"><div>` is not right closed `</div>`

Comment: @pleinx Thank you.

Comment: @SandrinaPereira Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome :) good luck for your project

Comment: check my answer, sorry the delay, i tried to improve your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.card` was stacked because you used `position: absolute`

**Checkou**t this fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/qugzfpxj/)

**Changing CSS:**

```
.card {
  perspective: 600px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  transition: all .3s;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

**Notice**: Close right your div
`<div class="face back"></div>`

Comment: I am facing a problem with size() method. I am using jQuery3.1.0 - I have checked the jQuery documentation they say length() is the new replacement for size(). here is the link - http://codepen.io/amirhasan/pen/qarQzq  please tell me  what is wrong with the code - in the selectCard() method  OR as a whole!

Comment: Please update your codepen. jQuery doesnt work because you dont include it as external ressource. One thing who i directly see is your selector. Please change `$(this).click(selectCard);` to `$('.card').click(selectCard);` .... another thing, you dont need anymore  the init of positions (`// initialise each card's position `) this we do already via css

Comment: Check this how you can select current clicked `.card`: https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/qugzfpxj/1/

Comment: I am getting how the above code is working  but in the browser I am getting an error- length() id not a function - 'if($(".card-flipped").length()>1 )'  in the selectCard() function-   please help me fix this problem. I am   making a card matching game. link: http://codepen.io/amirhasan/pen/qarQzq

Comment: Please replace next time `<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>` to `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` this save time. And your problem is you use `.length()` as function. Just type `if($(".card-flipped").length>1)` ( and for other lengt() too!)

Comment: you have small typo. change this `$(this).addClass(".card-flipped");` to `$(this).addClass("card-flipped");` (means remove the dot on addClass())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125984/discussion-between-amir-hasan-and-pleinx).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need javascript to align the cards, you can do it only with CSS:

First add clearfix to the parent `#cards` and add width and height:

```
#cards {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#cards:before,
#cards:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

#cards:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

And then add some margin between each card:

```
.card{
    width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
    float: left; //to align each card
    margin: 15px; //to give some space between them
}

//this says: each 4th card add a bigger margin-left, to align better the row.
.card:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Here's a working example:
http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/xEaJjw

Comment: please explain this peice of code:
 card:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  margin-left: 40px;
}     And <br/>  $(".card:first-child").clone().appendTo("#cards");               (I am  new to jQuery and CSS)

Comment: and in the following piece of   ' code: .front{
 background: GRAY url(../images/deck.png) 0 -480px;
}'    are we using the 0 -480px part of the deck.png ?     how is this working ?

Comment: Sure. `nth-of-type()` is a css selector to target specific childrens. You can understand it better with this amazing article: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/ . The `.clone()`function what it does is create a copy of  ".card:first-child" and then `.appendTo()` that copy to the end of #cards. For more you can see here: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: `0 -480px` is a short-had for `background-position:` is the coordinate `x y` of your image. See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/background-position/

Comment: means we are cloning the part that in 0 -480px of deck.png ? am I correct? But still I don't understand why is it  -480px - negative sign!! please explain.

Comment: You are cloning the element .card. 0 -480px is the coordinate of the image that it's using. 0px to left and -480px to top. I can't see the image so i can't explain you exactly what is "cropping". sorry :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125926/discussion-between-amir-hasan-and-sandrina-pereira).